# How do I publish ASP.NET Web Api to a MVC Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have two projects. One larger project which is my main website. And i have developed a ASP.NET WebApi for this same site (based on the same model/logic as what is behind this website). I would like to supply this API as an add-on for my main website. Now I'm looking for a way to optionally deploy/add the API together with the website.

My idea was that I copy the DLL of my WebApi into the bin folder of my normal MVC website and that I use reflection on start up to add the routes from the API controllers in my DLL. But when I copy the WebApi DLL into the bin folder, ASP.NET is running trough the global.asax.cs code from the WebApi and already starts trying to handle the routes.

My questions:

Is this a good way of adding WebApi functionality to and existing project, or are there better ways?
Is there a way to prevent my copied WebApi DLL from starting automatically?

Comment: why not having the asp.net web api implemented directly in the mvc site?

Comment: Because it is an add-on and not a complete site. The idea is that people can order the api with the existing product, and the only thing that we need to do than is upload the dll.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an application setting that prevents the WebApi application startup from registering the routes. After doing so, you might be able to handle things on your own.